# Android Things - passive speaker is too quiet

Tags: android, android-things

I'm trying to use my passive speaker connected to an I2S DAC on Raspberry Pi 3 (the DAC is here - https://www.dhgate.com/product/pcm5102-dac-decoder-i2s-player-assembled/373235584.html)

I've successfully enabled the I2S in config.txt and initialized an audio driver for playback. It works perfectly, but the volume is very quiet. I'm trying to set the music stream volume to max, but the volume doesn't increase.

The speaker I use has 4 Ohm and outputs 5W

Has anybody some experience with I2S audio output who can help to solve my volume problem? Or maybe I gave to use another speaker or additional hardware?

**UPD** Here is my code regarding the volume change

`AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);`

Comment: Please add some source code especially code for changing volume of stream. Also You can take a loot at [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/androidthings-assistant/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fio2017#0) tutorial, especially to [that](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/androidthings-assistant/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fio2017#3) step.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko Well, the tutorial you have sent is about the Google Assistant usage, but I'm going to write the code from scratch without this...

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that the output volume on Android Things is somehow set to roughly half. I've tested with three different RPi 3 Bs, using the analog line out, two separate USB sound cards and the Adafruit MAX 98357A amplifier (using I2S bus output), and all produce sound at an incorrect level. I'm comparing this against booting those same devices into Raspbian or attaching the USB or amp to a different machine. My conclusion is that there must be a low-level issue in Android Things itself. See also this issue: https://github.com/androidthings/sample-googleassistant/issues/54